# Defining Class to generate HTML file

Tags: c#, html, class

I am trying to generate a HTML file using a class,but it does not generate more than one HTML tag,
I was wondering if you could tell me what I can do in order to generate multiple tags in my HTML file.
Here is the code:

```
public class GuidClass
{
    public string htmlstringfirst = "<HTML><HEADER><title>My Web-page</title></HEADER><BODY>";
    public string htmlstringend = "</form></BODY></HTML>";
    public string htmlstring = "";
    public GuidClass(string title, string type, string defaultvalue)
    {
        htmlstring += "\r\n<input id = " + '"' + System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + '"' + "title =" + '"' + title + '"' + "type=" + '"' + type + '"' + ">" + defaultvalue + "</input><br>";
    }
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    GuidClass objGuid = new GuidClass(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\test.htm", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.Write(objGuid.htmlstringfirst + objGuid.htmlstring + objGuid.htmlstringend);
        }
    }
    htmlLoadWebbrowser1.LoadHTML(@"D:\test.htm");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `how to generate multiple tags`? What kind of tags? use loops.

Comment: I have a button and three textboxes in my form,whenever I click on the button,I want the values of textboxes to be added to my html file.
But whenever I click on my button,it resets is value.

Comment: `objGuid.htmlstring+=textBox1.Text;` ?

Comment: @I4V :Thanks,but my problems is a  bit more complicated,
I guess I am making a mistake in my Class,but I do not know where,I appreciate it if you help me out

Comment: @IRSOG :Thanks a lot,but please make it with a class,
Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this case use a `web-browser` control
         you can easily insert element to web-`browser` as a child,with web browser you have a lot of advantage.

you can build you page and save html page.this is a simple example but you can do more:

```
//From.cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Html_Class _Html_Class = new Html_Class();
    private void Add_Element_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement userelement = _Html_Class.Create_Tag("p");
        userelement.InnerText = "Something";
        _Html_Class.Addend_Child(userelement);
        var s = _Html_Class.Get_Source();
    }

}
//Html_Class.cs
public class Html_Class
{
    private WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

    public Html_Class()
    {
       wb.DocumentText = "<HTML><HEADER><title>My Web-page</title></HEADER><BODY></BODY></HTML>";
    }

    public HtmlElement Create_Tag(string tagname)
    {
        return  wb.Document.CreateElement("tagname");
    }

    public void Addend_Child(HtmlElement element)
    {
        wb.Document.Body.AppendChild(element);
    }

    public string Get_Source()
    {
     return (wb.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.HTMLDocument).documentElement.outerHTML;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use WebBrowser control and then instead of calling it like this:

```
 htmlLoadWebbrowser1.LoadHTML(@"D:\test.htm");
```

You could instead call it like this

```
 webBrowser1.Navigate(@"D:\test.htm");
```

I tested using your own code and it works.

Secondly, i think you miss also one small thing but i think it is important,
namely, in your code you have:

```
public string htmlstringfirst = "<HTML><HEADER><title>My Web-page</title></HEADER><BODY>";
```

Did you not forget to add the form element starting tag? like this:

```
public string htmlstringfirst = "<HTML><HEADER><title>My Web-page</title></HEADER><BODY><form>";
```

Comment: Thanks I had forgotten the  tag"<Form>",but it was not the problem,the problem is that this class should make me able to add a HTML tag whenever I call it,but it just generates one tag
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of `GuidClass` is appending to `htmlstring`. But as it stands, each time you create a new `GuidClass` it will have its own copy of `htmlstring` that is initialised to an empty string and then appended to in the constructor.

Instead, you need to store previous values between calls.

The "least code change" approach to getting this to work would be to change

```
public string htmlstring = "";
```

to

```
public static string htmlstring = "";
```

(where `static` means that all instances of the class share the same variable).

You will also need to change the point where you call it from `objGuid.htmlstring` to `GuidClass.htmlstring`.

While this will get you working in the short term, there are lots of improvements that could be made to make the code tidier and easier to maintain. Stack Overflow isn't really the place for that type of feedback, but the helpful folks at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ will be able to point you in the right direction.